# Set .HTA to open at specific display location

Tags: windows, hta

Have been given an HTML Application .HTA file, but it always opens to the upper left.

1) What can I add to the script so it opens at far right?
2) Can I force it to open in Display 2 (which is to the right of Display 1) instead of Display 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.moveTo(screen.width+2), (screen.height+2);
</script>
```

inserted after

```
<script language="JavaScript">
```

moved the HTA to appear just a skosh past the left edge of Display 2 (assuming Display 1 is to the left of Display 2). 
Problem solved!

Comment: Not quite, I've my default screen on the right, your code would hide the app totally ...

Comment: Standard? There's no standard of how you should position your screens. The idea of the comment is, that this is much more complex, and an SO answer should be as generic as possible.

Comment: @Teemu, I should have said 'less popular', you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the first monitor on the right, just replace

```
window.moveTo(screen.width+2), (screen.height+2);
```

With:

```
window.moveTo(-screen.width), (screen.height);
```